# Retorno Null de um objeto no controller - RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Olá! tenho o seguinte trecho de código de um controlador chamado ProdutosController:

```
  def index
    @produtos = Produto.all
  end

  def gerarlog
    @produtos.each do |produto|
      File.open('produtosBD.yml', 'a') do |arquivo|
        arquivo.puts YAML.dump("ID: "+produto.id)
        arquivo.puts ""
        arquivo.puts YAML.dump("Nome: "+produto.nome)
        arquivo.puts ""
        arquivo.puts YAML.dump("Descrição: "+produto.descricao)
        arquivo.puts ""
      end
    end
  end
```

meu arquivo routes está assim:

```
  resources :produtos do
    collection do
      get :gerarlog
    end
  end
  post "produtos/gerarlog"
  root 'home#index'
```

Quando eu chamo a função gerarlog com um click de botão na view, aparece o erro:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

acrescentei esta linha:

produtos = Produto.all

logo depois da definição da função gerarlog e funcionou.
sem mais '-'

Answer (score 0):

Não é a maneira correta, mas, no seu caso, pode solucionar o seu problema. Recomendo a adição do código completo para análise.

```
def index
  @produtos = Produto.all
end

def gerarlog
  @produtos = Produto.all
  @produtos.each do |produto|
    File.open('produtosBD.yml', 'a') do |arquivo|
      arquivo.puts YAML.dump("ID: "+produto.id)
      arquivo.puts ""
      arquivo.puts YAML.dump("Nome: "+produto.nome)
      arquivo.puts ""
      arquivo.puts YAML.dump("Descrição: "+produto.descricao)
      arquivo.puts ""
    end
  end
end
```